# Determining whether a string is transformable into another by repetitively increasing its prefixes alphabetically

Tags: c++, algorithm, programming-challenge, strings

Here's [Alice and Strings](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/string-algorithm/basics-of-string-manipulation/practice-problems/algorithm/aliceandstrings-9da62aa7/), a programming challenge on hackerearth:

> Two strings \$A\$ and \$B\$ comprising of lower case English letters
>   are compatible if they are equal or can be made equal by following
>   this step **any number of times**:
>
> - Select a prefix from the string \$A\$ (possibly empty), and increase the alphabetical value of all the characters in the prefix by the same
>     valid amount. For example if the string is `xyz` and we select the
>     prefix `xy` then we can convert it to `yz` by increasing the
>     alphabetical value by 1. But if we select the prefix `xyz` then we
>     cannot increase the alphabetical value.
>
> Your task is to determine if given strings \$A\$ and \$B\$ are
>   compatible.
>
> #### Input format
>
> First line: String \$A\$
>
> Next line: String \$B\$
>
> #### Output format
>
> For each test case, print `YES` if string \$A\$ can be converted to
>   string \$B\$, otherwise print `NO`.
>
> #### Constraints
>
> $$
>   \DeclareMathOperator{\len}{len}
>   1 \leq \len(A) \leq 1\,000\,000 \\
>   1 \leq \len(B) \leq 1\,000\,000 \\
>   $$

Can you please review my solution to it?  Please comment on any aspect to improve such as readability, comment usage, further improvements on speed/memory usage, etc.

```
/*
HackerEarth
https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/string-algorithm/basics-of-string-manipulation/practice-problems/algorithm/aliceandstrings-9da62aa7/
*/

#include <iostream>

/*
Recusrsively checks if string A can be converted to B by incrementing the prefixes:

eg:
A = abaca B = cdbda
[step 1]bcbda (prefix abac incremented by 1)
[step 2]bc[b]da cd[b]da (don't take bcb as a prefix because b is already matched)
[step 3]cdbda -----> so convertible (incrementing prefix bc)
*/
bool transformable(std::string& A, std::string& B, int last_index)
{
    if (A.compare(0, last_index, B, 0, last_index) == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (A[last_index] == B[last_index])
        {
            return transformable(A, B, --last_index);
        }
        else
        {
            if (A[last_index] > B[last_index])
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                while(A[last_index] != B[last_index])
                {
                    for(int i = 0; i <= last_index; i++)
                    {
                        A[i] += ('b' - 'a');
                    }
                }

                return transformable(A, B, --last_index);
            }

        }

    }

}

int main()
{
    std::string A;
    std::string B;

    std::cin >> A >> B;

    if (A.length() != B.length())
    {
        std::cout << "NO" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    if (transformable(A, B, A.length() - 1))
        std::cout << "YES" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "NO" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Code review

In general, the code looks nice and follows consistent styles.  Some small observations:

- Missing `#include <string>`.
- Avoid `std::endl` when `\n` suffices.  `std::endl` flushes the buffer, while `\n` does not.  Unnecessary flushing can cause performance degradation.  See [`std::endl` vs `\n`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/213907/9716597).  Use

  ```
  std::cout << "YES\n";
  ```

  instead of

  ```
  std::cout << "YES" << std::endl;
  ```

  unless flushing is a requirement from the website (I hope not).
- Since we are depending on lowercase letters being continuously encoded anyway, `'B' - 'A'` is just `1`.  And `A[i] += 1` becomes `++A[i]`.

## Better algorithm

That said, the logic of the code is overly convoluted.  The many levels of nested control statements make it hard to follow the code.  There is a much simpler algorithm to do it: to determine whether `A` is transformable into `B`,

- take the differences between the corresponding positions `B[i] - A[i]`;
- form a sequence out of these differences;
- append the sequence by 0 (to prevent cases like `bbbbb => aaaaa`);
- test if this sequence is sorted in non-ascending order.

For example:

- for `A = "abcde"`, `B = "ccdde"`, the sequence of differences is `21100`, so the transformation is possible (`abcde => bcdde => ccdde`);
- for `A = "abcde"`, `B = "bbcce"`, the sequence of differences is `10010`, so the transformation is impossible (try it).

Here's (roughly) how I would put everything together:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>

bool transformable(std::string_view a, std::string_view b)
{
    if (a.size() != b.size()) {
        return false;
    }
    std::vector<int> diff_sequence(a.size() + 1);
    std::transform(b.begin(), b.end(), a.begin(), diff_sequence.begin(), std::minus<>{});
    diff_sequence.back() = 0;
    return std::is_sorted(diff_sequence.begin(), diff_sequence.end(), std::greater<>{});
}

int main()
{
    std::string A;
    std::string B;

    std::cin >> A >> B;

    if (transformable(A, B)) {
        std::cout << "YES\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "NO\n";
    }
}
```

([live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vFagC0QSsVQHprIc))

(Replace `std::string_view` with `const std::string&` and remove the `#include <string_view>` if C++17 is not available, which IIRC is the case with competitive programming sites.)

The `transformable` function can be simplified with the [range-v3 library](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/index.html):

```
namespace views = ranges::views;

bool transformable(std::string_view a, std::string_view b)
{
    return ranges::is_sorted(
        views::concat(
            views::transform(b, a, std::minus<>{}),
            views::single(0)
        ), std::greater<>{});
}
```

([live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GlfRzk9f32hinqnq))